# How to Determine how much stack space an embeded program is using

Tags: c, stack, embedded, stack-trace

I am wondering what the best way to Determine how much stack space a program is using, are there any techniques or tools to generate the statistics, rather than counting by hand?

The program is hoping to analyze is a C program in code composer, if that makes a difference.

Thank you

Comment: It probably is important, because knowing the tool-chain allows the consideration of techniques provided by that toolchain rather then generic techniques.  However "Code Composer" tells us only about the IDE, not what compiler/linker is used or what version or for what target or whether you are using DSP/BIOS or other OS.  That is the information you should include. BTW: you should read this: http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Stack_issues#Finding_out_static_stack_usage.

Comment: [Here is a good blog post](http://embeddedgurus.com/stack-overflow/2009/03/computing-your-stack-size/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can fill the stack ram with some pattern (0xDEADBEEF for example) and then run for a while then examine the stack to see how much was used.  You would still have to do the analysis to find the deepest paths, and then generate the deepest nested interrupts on top of that if it is ever possible in the application.

Comment: This is a good secondary check, but using the compiler's stack depth plus manual static analysis is the best way to go.  The stack RAM approach assumes that your dynamic test hits the deepest stack usage, which may only occur in some error path that isn't hit in the dynamic test.

Comment: exactly you still have to do the analysis.  If you have done the analysis and you have created the worst case situation, then the two should line up.   in any case if the analysis and the measured dont match you need to figure out why.

Answer (score 2):

There is some info about running the static analysis tool on TI's website [here](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Stack_and_Heap_size_requirements).  Generally, static analysis will tell you how much stack is used by the deepest call tree from main(), but it won't include the ISRs.  You need to manually look at the call tree and add in the ISR call depth.  If you have several priority levels of ISRS, don't forget that a higher priority ISR can interrupt a lower priority one.

Comment: Note: Some architectures have a separate stack for interrupts, but in either case if interrupts are nestable, you need to consider worst-case nesting scenarios.  Also if using an RTOS such as TI's DSP/BIOS or SYS/BIOS there will be separate stacks for each task context; static analysis will show the deepest stack for each thread entry-point, but will not account for additional stack required for storing task context.

Comment: It also breaks at function pointers and may not fully understand virtual member functions.